# Showing two items instead of three on initial load - WordPress/Owl Carousel

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I've got a problem regarding Owl Carousel on a Wordpress site. When I visit the site for the first time the owl carousel shows two items instead of three as added in the script. The problem is that I doesn't show the two items as it should. if it was the plan, but rather two and 1/6 of the third item:
[Owl carousel problem (2 items with a bit of 3rd)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03pLl.png)

When I reload/refresh the site it shows three items as it should:
[Owl carousel as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIB2o.png).

My script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:false,
        margin:30,
        URLhashListener:true,
        startPosition: 'URLHash',
        responsiveClass:true,
        nav:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
                nav:true,
                slideBy: 1
            },
            767:{
                items:2,
                nav:true,
                slideBy: 2
            },
            1020:{
                items:3,
                nav:true,
                slideBy: 3
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You can check the site [here](https://test.smagaarhus.dk/) and see the carousel at the bottom (I'm working on the site, so there might be some changes).

Any clues would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the default value in the **items: 3**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop: false,
            margin: 30,
            items: 3,
            URLhashListener: true,
            startPosition: 'URLHash',
            responsiveClass: true,
            nav: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true,
                    slideBy: 1
                },
                767: {
                    items: 2,
                    nav: true,
                    slideBy: 2
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

(Off topic) Also, you should not re-specify parameters such as: **nav: true**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop: false,
            margin: 30,
            items: 3,
            URLhashListener: true,
            startPosition: 'URLHash',
            responsiveClass: true,
            nav: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                    slideBy: 1
                },
                767: {
                    items: 2,
                    slideBy: 2
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

---

You may need to wait until the page is fully loaded, try it:

```
(function ($) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            loop: false,
            margin: 30,
            URLhashListener: true,
            startPosition: "URLHash",
            responsiveClass: true,
            nav: true,
            responsive: { 0: { items: 1, slideBy: 1 }, 767: { items: 2, slideBy: 2 }, 1020: { items: 3, slideBy: 3 } },
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but it doesn't seem to respect the default value in items, but rather takes the responsive item value. The problem on first load is still there, but I could fix it with a simple max-width.

Comment: https://test.smagaarhus.dk/ where is your call script? Ok i found

Comment: Can you do as I said? So I can check if this is not working? (you didn't fix it) https://test.smagaarhus.dk/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_single_ae050634e6cecb4946f00808a4b6d461.js?ver=5.5

Comment: I added a final example

Comment: I tried it before, but didn't clear cache, since I was logged in as admin. I've added your suggestion and remove the max-width I added.

Comment: I looked at the documentation, you are right the problem is not in the settings responsive breakpoint work by formula min-width, try to return your settings, I think I guess what the problem is

Comment: It is reverted back to a mix of your suggestion and the initial script :)

Comment: Problem in resize event of plugin, since after resizing the window it starts working, try after loading and initializing the plugin to use the method: $(window).trigger('resize');
or $owl.trigger('resize.owl.carousel'); or $owl.trigger('resized.owl.carousel'); or $owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

Comment: I'll try to write an example in the answer, and you try to play around with this

Comment: try calling the plugin after loading the document (i added example to answer)

Comment: The problem was that you initialize the plugin before the styles were loaded, and the plugin did the wrong calculations, which should have been updated after the page was loaded using the above methods (in the comments), or you just have to wait for the styles to load that's exactly what you did, good luck!